# Dataloader in Pytorch is slow when data grows

Tags: python, performance, deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader

### Question

1. when `Dataset` returns a variable named `rf`, which's shape is `[128, 1, 40, 64, 64]`, it's fast.
2. when `Dataset` returns two variable named `rf` and `raw_data`, shaped `[128, 1, 40, 64, 64]` and `[128, 1, 40, 128, 64]`, it's very slow.

### Test

1. Through whole dataset of 1 and doing nothing, it takes **0.8 min**.
2. Through whole dataset of 2 and doing nothing, it takes **17 min**.

### Code

#### Dataset

```
class FallDatasetWith3DFFT(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, raw_data_path, data_path, filelist, mode=0, dataaug=False):
        something...

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        filename = self.filelist[index]
        file_path = os.path.join(self.data_path, filename)
        rf = np.load(file_path)

        filename = filename + '.npz'
        raw_data = np.load(os.path.join(self.raw_data_path, filename))
        return raw_data, rf, labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.filelist)
    
    def pre_process(self, rf):
        # (40, 128, 64)
        rf = region_propose(rf)
        rf = normalization(rf)
        rf = standardization(rf)
        return rf
```

#### Test

```
train_dl = DataLoader(DatasetClass, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, num_workers=5)
f = True
time_start = time.time()
for raw_data, rf in train_dl:
   if f:
       print(raw_data.shape)
       print(processed_data.shape)
       f = False
time_end = time.time()
print(
    f"batch size : {BATCH_SIZE},\
    Time:{(time_end - time_start)/60}min"
    
)
```

I have tried the `num_works` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for this problem. It's because that I Put the `rf` on Solid state drive and `raw_data` in Mechanical hard drive, so later is very slow.....